# How to send App to App message

Tags: android, sms

Is there a way to send messages directly from application to application? I'm making an app that needs verification from another phone, but I only send the messages via SMS, so there is a big chance that a false message having the same format might end up being recognized by the application as a legit one.

Comment: do you mean application on one phone sends a message to another one?

Comment: yes, and if possible, I don't want it to pass by the inbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both phones are in close proximity to each other, you could make a bluetooth connection and transfer the data that way.  It would work like that Bump app that transfers files when the phones are bumped together.

As a work around to the way you are doing it now, you could do a simple encryption of the messages so that they are not plain text and won't match a real text message.  If you wanted to make it pretty, you could encode the data in a picture so it doesn't look like a garbage text to the end user.

Comment: Sorry, but I need something that will work remotely. I was hoping that I could encode text that smartphones won't be able to type directly so that it would be recognized as a message sent by the application. I am assuming that people can simply copy whatever was written on that message and the application would still assume that it was sent by the application

Comment: I read somewhere in the forums that it is impossible (or at least they said it is impossible) for an application to intercept the message, read it, and delete it before it goes to the inbox. I would like to ask if this is really possible, because if so, then I won't have to worry about the content of the message being known to the user anymore.

Comment: It is possible, but you would have to replace the stock Android messenger app with your own in order to trap the incoming message the way you want.  If I understand you correctly, you already have the ability to get the message and read it, just want to delete it before it hits the inbox right?  You may not be able to kill it before it hits the inbox, but you could delete the message immediately after it hits in the inbox.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible. For functionality like this you would usually use server, and, maybe Google Cloud2Device to send Push messages.

Comment: I was hoping for a much simpler answer, isn't there a workaround for secure app to app communication?